# Specify the partition # based on date range for that pkey value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, partitioning, sql-server-2017

We have a DW query that needs to extract data from a very large table around 10 TB which is partitioned by `datetime` column lets say time to purge data based on this column everyday. So my understanding is each partition has worth a day of data. From storage (SSMS GUI) tab I see # of partitions is `1995`.

There is no clustered index on this table as its mostly intended for write operations. Just a design by vendor.

```
SELECT 
    a.*
FROM dbo.VLTB AS a
CROSS APPLY
(   
    VALUES($PARTITION.a_func(a.time))
) AS c (pid)
WHERE c.pid = 1896;
```

Currently query submitted is as

```
SELECT * from dbo.VLTB
WHERE time >= convert(datetime,'20210601',112)
AND time < convert(datetime,'20210602',112)
```

So replacing inequality predicates with equality to look in that days specific partition might help. Users via app can control dates when sending but how will they manage if we want them to use partition # as per first query

Question

How do I find a way in above query to find partition number for that day rather than me inserting like for **06/01 I had to give 1896 part#**. Is there a better way to have script find the part# to avoid all partitions being scanned and can insert correct part# in where clause query?

Thank you

Comment: Please provide sample data + expected results (as formatted text not images).

Comment: Maybe `WHERE c.pid = $PARTITION.a_func(@someDate)`